# Scala Netty How to create a simple client for byte data based protocol?

Tags: scala, netty

This Question is intended as a presentation of the problem that I have encountered while working on a current project. I will be answering below presenting my solution.

I am working on a project that requires me to connect to a data feed server that has a proprietary protocol to transfer data, essentially coded in the data section of the TCP protocol in GZIP format and needs to be extracted.

The [sample application](https://gist.github.com/autronix/6c60e2dd7876845bc2ad) for the data protocol from the data provider uses a simple socket in Java. I want to adapt it to scala/netty. Additionally, it is worth noting that the data provided may be spread over multiple packets.

I have been looking for simple and concise examples on how to use Netty.io to create a simple client application, but all examples seem overly complicated and lacked enough explanation to simply achieve this purpose.
More importantly a lot of the netty/scala examples are oriented toward server applications.

The "[Getting Started](http://netty.io/wiki/user-guide-for-4.x.html)" netty tutorial also lacks enough explanations to make it easy to navigate when actually getting started.

The question is, how to implement a simple netty application that connects to a server, receives the data and parses the results?

Here are some of the examples I have looked at in order to attempt understanding this concept:

- [Echo Client Handler](https://github.com/kxbmap/netty4-example-scala/tree/master/src/main/scala/com/github/kxbmap/netty/example/echo)
- [Scala By The Bay example](https://github.com/gsoltis/ScalaByTheBay/tree/master/src/main/scala/com/firebase/sbtb)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've run into this problem while trying to replicate a java application using sockets into a the more complex approach of using Netty.

The way I solved the issue is by getting to understand the various elements of the netty library required for establishing a connection:

- The [NioEventLoopGroup](http://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/channel/nio/NioEventLoopGroup.html)
- The [Bootstrap](http://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/bootstrap/Bootstrap.html)
- The [Channel](http://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/channel/Channel.html)

These 3 elements ensure that the connection is created and managed for further processing.

Additionally, some other things elements are required when working with Netty:

- a Channel initializer, typically a custom object subclassed from [ChannelInitializer](http://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/channel/ChannelInitializer.html)
- an Decoder, which may be any type based on the type of messages on expects to receive, these are typically subclasses of [ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter](http://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/channel/ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.html)
- an Encoder, similar for Decoders but for outgoing messages, typically a subclass of [ChannelOutboundHandlerAdapter](http://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/channel/ChannelOutboundHandlerAdapter.html)
- a Handler, which essentially tells netty how to deal with the received data.

The channel initializer is in charge of preparing the [Pipeline](http://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/channel/ChannelPipeline.html), which essentially passes the inbound and outbound data through a series of "filters" in order to process the data at different levels, each level receiving the data processed by the previous encoder/decoder.

Here is how the pipeline works as presented in the netty documentation:

```
                                                    I/O Request
                                                via Channel or
                                            ChannelHandlerContext
                                                          |
      +---------------------------------------------------+---------------+
      |                           ChannelPipeline         |               |
      |                                                  \|/              |
      |    +---------------------+            +-----------+----------+    |
      |    | Inbound Handler  N  |            | Outbound Handler  1  |    |
      |    +----------+----------+            +-----------+----------+    |
      |              /|\                                  |               |
      |               |                                  \|/              |
      |    +----------+----------+            +-----------+----------+    |
      |    | Inbound Handler N-1 |            | Outbound Handler  2  |    |
      |    +----------+----------+            +-----------+----------+    |
      |              /|\                                  .               |
      |               .                                   .               |
      | ChannelHandlerContext.fireIN_EVT() ChannelHandlerContext.OUT_EVT()|
      |        [ method call]                       [method call]         |
      |               .                                   .               |
      |               .                                  \|/              |
      |    +----------+----------+            +-----------+----------+    |
      |    | Inbound Handler  2  |            | Outbound Handler M-1 |    |
      |    +----------+----------+            +-----------+----------+    |
      |              /|\                                  |               |
      |               |                                  \|/              |
      |    +----------+----------+            +-----------+----------+    |
      |    | Inbound Handler  1  |            | Outbound Handler  M  |    |
      |    +----------+----------+            +-----------+----------+    |
      |              /|\                                  |               |
      +---------------+-----------------------------------+---------------+
                      |                                  \|/
      +---------------+-----------------------------------+---------------+
      |               |                                   |               |
      |       [ Socket.read() ]                    [ Socket.write() ]     |
      |                                                                   |
      |  Netty Internal I/O Threads (Transport Implementation)            |
      +-------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

In the case of the question's original context, there are no preset decoders that allow for parsing custom data with predetermined bytes. Essentially this means that custom decoders for Inbound data must be created.

Let's start by going over the basics of the connection to be initiated as a client application:

```
    import io.netty.bootstrap.Bootstrap
    import io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup
    import io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel
    import io.netty.channel.socket.SocketChannel

    object App {
      def main(args: Array[String]){
        connect()
      }

      def connect() { 
        val host = "host.example.com"
        val port = 9999 
        val group = new NioEventLoopGroup() // starts the event loop group

        try {
          var b = new Bootstrap() // creates the netty bootstrap 
            .group(group) // associates the NioEventLoopGroup to the bootstrap
            .channel(classOf[NioSocketChannel]) // associates the channel to the bootstrap
            .handler(MyChannelInitializer) // provides the handler for dealing with the incoming/outgoing data on the channel


          var ch = b.connect(host, port).sync().channel() //initiates the connection to the server and links it to the netty channel

          ch.writeAndFlush("SERVICE_REQUEST") // sends the request to the server

          ch.closeFuture().sync() // keeps the connection alive instead of shutting down the channel after receiving the first packet
        }
        catch {
          case t: Throwable => t.printStackTrace(); group.shutdownGracefully() 
        }
        finally {
          group.shutdownGracefully() // Shutdown the event group
        }
      }
    }
```

`MyChannelInitializer` called while initiating the bootstrap is the part that will take care of telling the program how to handle the incoming and outgoing data messages:

```
    import io.netty.channel.ChannelInitializer
    import io.netty.channel.socket.SocketChannel
    import io.netty.handler.codec.string.StringEncoder

    object MyChannelInitializer extends ChannelInitializer[SocketChannel] {

      val STR_ENCODER = new StringEncoder // Generic StringEecoder from netty to simply allow a string to be prepared and sent out to the server

      def initChannel(ch: SocketChannel) {
        val pipeline = ch.pipeline() // loads the pipeline associated with the channel

        // Decode Message
        pipeline.addLast("packet-decoder",MyPacketDecoder) // first data "filter" to extract the necessary bytes for the second filter
        pipeline.addLast("gzip-inflater", MyGZipDecoder) // second "filter" to unzip the contents

        // Encode String to send
        pipeline.addLast("command-encoder",STR_ENCODER) // String encoder for outgoing data

        // Handler
        pipeline.addLast("message-handler", MyMessageHandler) // Handles the end data after all "filters" have been applied
      }
    }
```

In this instance, the first pipeline item, `MyPacketDecoder` has been created as a subclass of [ReplayingDecoder](http://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/handler/codec/ReplayingDecoder.html), which provides a simple way to perform packet reconstruction in order to have all the necessary bytes for the message to use. (Simply put, wait for all bytes to be collected in the ByteBuf variable before moving on)

Getting to understand how [ByteBuf](http://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/buffer/ByteBuf.html) works is very important for this type of application especially the difference between the read and get methods, which allow respectively to read and move the read index or simply read the data without affecting the reader index.

An example of `MyPacketDecoder`is provided below

```
    import io.netty.handler.codec.ReplayingDecoder
    import io.netty.channel.ChannelHandlerContext
    import io.netty.buffer.ByteBuf
    import java.util.List

    object MyPacketDecoder extends ReplayingDecoder[Int] {

      val READ_HEADER = 0
      val READ_CONTENT = 1

      super.state(READ_HEADER) // sets the initial state of the Decoder by calling the superclass constructor

      var blockSize:Int = 0 // size of the data expected, published by the received data from the server, will vary according to your case, there may be additional header bytes before the actual data to be processed    

      def decode(ctx: ChannelHandlerContext,in: ByteBuf,out: List[AnyRef]): Unit = {

        var received_size = in.readableBytes()

        if(state() == READ_HEADER){
          blockSize = in.readInt() // header data with the size of the expected data to be received in the current and following packets if segmented

          checkpoint(READ_CONTENT) // change the state of the object in order to proceed to obtaining all the required bytes necessary for the message to be valid
        }
        else if(state() == READ_CONTENT){

          var bytes = new Array[Byte](blockSize)
          in.getBytes(0,bytes,0,blockSize) // adds collected bytes to the by array for the expected size as defined by the blockSize variable

          var frame = in.readBytes(blockSize) // creates the bytebuf to be passed to the next "filter"

          checkpoint(READ_HEADER) // changes the state preparing for the next message
          out.add(frame) // passes the data to the next "filter"
        }
        else {
          throw new Error("Case not covered Exception")
        }  
      }

    }
```

The previous code takes the received bytes from all the packets up to the expected byte size and passes it to the following pipeline level.

The next pipeline level deals with the GZIP decompression of the received data. This is ensured by the `MyGZipDecoder` object, which is defined as a subclass of the [ByteToMessageDecoder](https://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/handler/codec/ByteToMessageDecoder.html) abstract object in order to deal with Byte information as received data:

```
    import io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder
    import io.netty.channel.ChannelHandlerContext
    import io.netty.buffer.ByteBuf
    import java.net._
    import java.io._
    import java.util._
    import java.util.zip._
    import java.text._

    object MyGZipDecoder extends ByteToMessageDecoder {

      val MAX_DATA_SIZE = 100000

      var inflater = new Inflater(true)
      var compressedData = new Array[Byte](MAX_DATA_SIZE)
      var uncompressedData = new Array[Byte](MAX_DATA_SIZE)

      def decode(ctx: ChannelHandlerContext,in: ByteBuf,out: List[AnyRef]): Unit = {

        var received_size = in.readableBytes() // reads the number of available bytes

        in.readBytes(compressedData, 0, received_size) // puts the bytes into a Byte array

        inflater.reset();
        inflater.setInput(compressedData, 0, received_size) // prepares the inflater for decompression of the data
        var resultLength = inflater.inflate(uncompressedData) // decompresses the data into the uncompressedData Byte array

        var message = new String(uncompressedData) // generates a string from the uncompressed data

        out.add(message) // passes the data to the next pipeline level
      }
    }
```

This Decoder decompresses the compressed data received in the packets and sends the data to the next level as a String obtained from the decoded bytes received at that level.

The final piece of the puzzle is the `MyMessageHandler` object which essentially does the final processing on the data for the required purpose of the application. This is a subclass of [SimpleChannelInboundHandler](http://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/channel/SimpleChannelInboundHandler.html) with a String parameter expected as the message for the channel data:

```
    import io.netty.channel.{ChannelHandlerContext, SimpleChannelInboundHandler}
    import io.netty.channel.ChannelHandler.Sharable

    @Sharable
    object QMMessageHandler extends SimpleChannelInboundHandler[String] {

      def channelRead0(ctx: ChannelHandlerContext, msg: String) { 

        println("Handler => Received message: "+msg) 
        // Do your data processing here however you need for the application purposes

      }
    }
```

This essentially completes the requirements for this specific example of connecting to a server that provides data in a proprietary data protocol using GZip compression on the base packet data.

Hopefully this can serve as a good base for those attempting to implement similar scenarios, but the main idea is that it takes a bit of customization to create adapted processing for proprietary protocols.

Also, it is important noting that this type of implementation is not really intended for simple client-server connections but for applications that require the need for the distributability/scalability of the data, which offered by the netty library (ie. many concurrent connections simultaneously and broadcasting the data).

I apologize in advance for any errors that I may have missed while writing this answer.

I hope this short tutorial can help others, as I personally had to spend some frustrating time figuring it out from bits and pieces all over the net.

Comment: Nice writeup, thank you for taking the time of doing this. You might be interested in this other (more functional) Netty+Scala project https://github.com/RichRelevance/scalaz-netty